# What's the Difference Between a Charm, an Enchantment, a Spell, and a Curse?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

From a recent question, I know a curse is intended to harm people, and I think a charm is an object with a special power, but I also think I remember the word having a different meaning in Harry Potter.  And I'm not clear if a curse has to be a spell or if it could be an enchantment or charm as well.

So what, exactly is the difference between a spell, an enchantment, a charm, and a curse?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a description of spell types as J.K. Rowling classifies them:

> **Spell**: The generic term for a piece of magic.
>   **Charm**: Does not fundamentally alter the properties of the subject of the spell, but adds, or changes, properties. Turning a teacup into a rat would be a spell, whereas making a teacup dance would be a charm. The grey area comes with things like 'Stunning Spells', which on balance I think are Charms, but which I call spells for alliterative effect.
>   **Hexes**: Has a connotation of dark magic, as do jinxes, but of a minor sort. I see 'hex' as slightly worse. I usually use 'jinx' for spells whose effects are irritating but amusing.
>   **Curses**: Reserved for the worst kinds of dark magic.
>   [J.K. Rowling's Personal Website](http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=24)

So that's a basic linear explanation of the different levels of magic.

Lily's protective magic given to Harry when she gave her life to save his has been referred to in canon as an enchantment.

Comment: Anything on enchantments?

Comment: @Slytherincess, you are hard to compete against.  You're fast, you know your Potterverse, and you're thorough.  You are the Perry the Platypus to my Doofenshmirtz.

Comment: Didn't you answer this exact question a couple months ago?

Comment: @TangoOversway -- No, not on JKR's website, but enchantments are referred to throughout canon, the most obvious being Lily's protective enchantments placed on Harry when she chose to die instead of stepping aside to let Voldemort take a shot at Harry. Protective enchantments are mentioned as well -- such as enchantments protecting Hogwarts. Perhaps this is mentioned in *Hogwarts: A History* (and repeated by Hermione).

Comment: @Kevin -- I don't *think* so, but I *answered* a similar question here a while back. As well, I just gave the same info in my response to TangoOversway's question regarding Dark Magic. :)

Comment: @DavidStratton -- Oh, do go on! No, but seriously, I don't believe I know more about Potterverse than anyone else is able to know. The only reason I answered this so quickly is that I coincidentally happened to have the info ready in another post and did a quick C&P. You are hardly a Doofenschmirtz (although that is absolutely a fantastic word!) :)

Comment: What about the Geminio curse? It is referred to as "curse" from Griphook in  DH, but it doesn't seem to be one of the worst kinds of Dark magic. It is true that it can generate a huge pile of objects that can crush a person, but I don't think that this spell was created with the intent of crushing people, so it should not be considered as evil per se.

Answer (score 0):

Charms would be less potent than enchantments,and Jinxes are only minor inconveniences while hexes and curses are much more potent, malicious and deadly by nature.
Also curse are mean to last for a long time or for ever/ until the subject dies.